# Sentences in columns SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm programming a little directory, with SQLite, python and tkinter. I have a problem when I insert more than one word in one column of the database, when I insert a name with more than two words it appears in {} (as it is shown in the picture) and not as it is in the other columns, how can I solve this?

[image]

Backend:

```
     import sqlite3

    def connect():
        """Set up a connection with the database."""
        conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
        cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
        cur_obj.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                        "book (id integer PRIMARY KEY, "
                                "title text, "
                                "name text, "
                                "email text, "
                                "address text, "
                                "telephone integer, "
                                "cellphone integer, "
                                "description text, "
                                "company text, "
                                "addresscompany text, "
                                "telephonecompany integer, "
                                "cellphonecompany integer, "
                                "company text)")
        conn_obj.commit()
        conn_obj.close()

    def insert(title, name, email, address, telephone, cellphone, description, company, addresscompany, telephonecompany, cellphonecompany, comment):
        """Insert entry into database."""
        conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
        cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
        cur_obj.execute("INSERT INTO book "
                        "VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, name, email, address, telephone, cellphone, description, company, addresscompany, telephonecompany, cellphonecompany, comment))
        conn_obj.commit()
        conn_obj.close()
    connect()

def view():
    """View all database entries."""
    conn_obj = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
    cur_obj = conn_obj.cursor()
    cur_obj.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows = cur_obj.fetchall()
    conn_obj.close()
    return rows
```

Frontend:

```
      from tkinter import *
        import backend

        def add_command():
            """Insert entry via button."""
            backend.insert(title_text.get(),
                            name_text.get(),
                            email_text.get(),
                            address_text.get(), 
                            telephone_text.get(),
                            cellphone_text.get(),
                            description_text.get(),
                            company_text.get(),
                            addresscompany_text.get(), 
                            telephonecompany_text.get(),
                            cellphonecompany_text.get(),
                            comment_text.get())
            listing.delete(0, END)
            listing.insert(END, 
                            (title_text.get(), 
                            name_text.get(),
                            email_text.get(),
                            address_text.get(), 
                            telephone_text.get(),
                            cellphone_text.get(),
                            description_text.get(),
                            company_text.get(),
                            addresscompany_text.get(), 
                            telephonecompany_text.get(),
                            cellphonecompany_text.get(),
                            comment_text.get()))
    def view_command():
        """View entries via button."""
        listing.delete(0, END)
        for row in backend.view():
            listing.insert(END, row)

    listing = Listbox(window, height = 6, width = 100)
    listing.grid(row = 4, column = 0, rowspan = 7, columnspan = 6)

window = Tk()
window.wm_title("Directory")

name_text = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable = name_text)
entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: Do you see the `{}` in the database, when running a `select` from the console (`sqlite3 Database.db`)?

Comment: no, the {} only appear on my GUI

Comment: How do you select these values in Python? Where is the code that selects them and passes them to the UI?

Comment: I just added the missing parts of the code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` mean that you are inserting a tuple where tkinter expects a string. Explicitly convert your lists or tuples to strings before inserting the data into a widget (curly braces are how the underlying tcl interpreter represents lists).

This is easily illustrated with this simple bit of code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
data = ("one", "two three", "four")
root = tk.Tk()
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
listbox.insert("end", data)
root.mainloop()
```

The above code will result in a window that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The bottom line is that the `insert` method expects a string, not a list of strings. You need to explicitly convert your data to a string before calling `insert`.

For example:

```
listbox.insert("end", " ".join(data))
```

[image]

Comment: I understand, but I´m already converting my input into a string with StringVar()

Comment: @matilarab: you are using `StringVar`, but you are giving the `insert` method a _list_ of `StringVar`s. This method expects a string, not a list.